# How to keep the first window constant in sliding window?

Tags: python

I am using the following code to apply a sliding window on time-series data. I want to set up my first window as fixed and then apply the sliding window as shown below in the desired output.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7,8,9,10]})

def sliding_window(data, size):
    return [ data[x:x+size] for x in range( len(data) - size + 1 ) ]


sliding_window(df, 7)
```

> output

```
[   B
 0  0
 1  1
 2  2
 3  3
 4  4
 5  5
 6  6,
    B
 1  1
 2  2
 3  3
 4  4
 5  5
 6  6
 7  7,
    B
 2  2
 3  3
 4  4
 5  5
 6  6
 7  7
 8  8,
    B
 3  3
 4  4
 5  5
 6  6
 7  7
 8  8
 9  9,
      B
 4    4
 5    5
 6    6
 7    7
 8    8
 9    9
 10  10]
```

**Desired output**
Example:

I am using the fixed window of size 5 here. and it always should be the first window, and the sliding window is same as before except it slides from first window. Like the left figure in the images..
[image]

```
[   B
 0  0
 1  1
 2  2
 3  3
 4  4,
    B
 0  0
 1  1
 2  2
 3  3
 4  4
 5  5,
    B
 0  0
 1  1
 2  2
 3  3
 4  4
 5  5
 6  6,
    B
 0  0
 1  1
 2  2
 3  3
 4  4
 5  5
 6  6
 7  7,
      B
 0  0
 1  1
 2  2
 3  3
 4  4
 5  5
 6  6
 7  7
 8  8,
     B
 0  0
 1  1
 2  2
 3  3
 4  4
 5  5
 6  6
 7  7
 8  8
 9  9,
     B
 0  0
 1  1
 2  2
 3  3
 4  4
 5  5
 6  6
 7  7
 8  8
 9  9
 10 10]
```

Comment: Your desired output is not a sliding window though

Comment: Why do you think this is not a sliding window? Is the right part in the figure is a sliding window?

Comment: the right part definitely is. Looks like the left part is called ["expanding window"](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-the-expanding-and-the-rolling-of-a-data-set).

Comment: Thank you. Could you please add the code to the right part if possible?

Comment: Your `sliding_window` function already implements this

Comment: so your answer is 'expanding window', correct?

Comment: Yes, absolutely correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def rolling_window_maybe(data, initial_size: int):
    return [ data[:initial_size + x] for x in range( len(data) - initial_size ) ]
```

For example:

```
data = [1,2,3,4]
size = 2

data[:size + 0] == [1,2]
data[:size + 1] == [1,2,3]
data[:size + 2] == [1,2,3,4]
```